# Keep data in the cell when formula is invalid in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the following custom formula in Excel file named Excel_Sample.xls:

```
GetData = Workbooks("data.xls").Worksheets("sht").Range("E1")
```

When the data.xls is open, open the Excel_Sample.xls, and the cell using this formula(say A1) could get the value of Cell E1 in data.xls.

However, close data.xls then:

Open Excel_Sample.xls In Excel 2003, the data in A1 is still there even if the formula of GetData isn't valid (cause the data.xls is closed.).

Open Excel_Sample.xls In Excel 2010, the data in A1 become #VALUE! cause the formula runs again and can get the data in data.xls.

What can I do to keep the data in Excel 2010 even the formula is invalid, just like 2003?

Answer (score 0):

> Open Excel_Sample.xls In Excel 2003, the data in A1 is still there even if the formula of GetData isn't valid (cause the data.xls is closed.).

That happens when the calculation is set to manual. Do this

1. Set the calculation to Automatic in the workbook which has the formula, if it is not already Automatic. You can do that under the Formulas Tab | Calculation Options
2. Open both the workbooks. Let the formulas update themselves.
3. Change the calculation to Manual
4. Close the workook from where the value is being picked up and you are done.

HTH

Comment: Hi, but when I open Excel_Sample.xls in Excel 2010 next time, the previous data will all be #VALUE! once the formula updates.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But it's not what I want. I've checked that the setting of excel 2003 is Automatic but it's able to hold the data. Why excel 2010 can't do this.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Can I see your Excel file which has the formula?